# How to select ranges for .SetSourceData for stacked bar chart?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I want to select ranges for .SetSourceData for my stacked bar chart.

My ranges are noncontiguous.  The start date is in column G, and the rest of the numbers are calculated in columns V through AI.

Currently this is only charting columns V through AI, and it's using column G as the horizontal axis label.

I tried adding the horizontal axis label range (column E) as the first .range argument to Union, but it then displays columns E & F (not sure where F came from) as the horizontal axis label.  Column G was nowhere to be found.

Is there a way to do this with SetSourceData, or do I have to individually set SeriesCollection for all 15 series?

```
Sub Create_Chart()
'
' Create_Chart Macro
'
Dim ganttChart As ChartObject
Dim sourceRange As Range

With Sheets("Projects")
    Set sourceRange = Union(.Range("G1:G70"), .Range("V1:AI70"))
End With

Set ganttChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(100, 50, 200, 200)

With ganttChart
With .Chart
    .ChartType = xlBarStacked
    .Legend.Delete
    .Parent.Width = 1224
    .Parent.Height = 828
    .SetSourceData Source:=sourceRange, PlotBy:=xlColumns
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet

    With .Axes(xlValue)
        '.MinimumScale = 41428
        '.MaximumScale = 41607
        .MajorUnit = 7
        .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "m/d"
        .TickLabels.Font.Size = 6
        .TickLabels.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    End With
    With .Axes(xlCategory)
        .ReversePlotOrder = True
        .TickLabelSpacing = 1
        .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "@"
        .TickLabels.Font.Size = 6
        .TickLabels.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    End With
End With
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try selecting the source range right before inserting the chart. Excel might start out using the correct range, so you don't need to define the source data.

An alternative approach is to add one series at a time:

```
Set ganttChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(100, 50, 200, 200)

' clean up first
' i declared as long
For i = 1 to ganttChart.SeriesCollection.Count
    ganttChart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
Next

' rColumn declared as range
For Each rColumn In Sheets("Projects").Range("V1:AI70").Columns
    With ganttChart.NewSeries
        .Values = rColumn
        .XValues = Sheets("Projects").Range("G1:G70")
    End With
Next
```